# eslint-plugin-import package is failing to recognise difference between external and internal directories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

In my `.eslintrc` I have:

```
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "caseInsensitive": true,
          "order": "asc"
        },
        "groups": [
          "builtin",
          "external",
          "internal",
          "parent",
          "sibling",
          "index"
        ],
        "newlines-between": "always-and-inside-groups",
        "pathGroups": [
          {
            "pattern": "react",
            "group": "external",
            "position": "before"
          }
        ],
        "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["builtin"]
      }
    ],
```

and

```
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "alwaysTryTypes": true,
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
      },
      "node": {
        "paths": "src"
      }
    }
  }
```

but in one of my files I have:

`import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"`

and a few lines below I have
`import {  ReservationStatus } from "generated/graphql"`

`react-to-print` is a third party and `generated/` is something local that I generate with apollo but it's not external

but I'm getting a complaint on the `import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"` saying

`react-to-print import should occur after import of generated/graphql eslint[import/order](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.27.5/docs/rules/order.md)`

but that's wrong, so what have I configured incorrectly?

Comment: You can add a path group and specify what's internal path  eg: ``` "pathGroups": [
    { 
      "pattern": "generated", 
      "group": "internal" 
    }, 
    
 ], ```

Comment: @RenaldoMateus can I not just ask it to consider anything under "src" as internal?

Comment: You said before that there is a conflict with plugin import identify generated/ as internal it's considered as external so I suggest specifying on import plugin settings that your generated is internal  { "pattern": "generated", "group": "internal" } , and I found this might be helpful https://dev.to/diballesteros/how-to-quickly-configure-eslint-for-import-sorting-2h73

Comment: Could you help us reproduce your issue? A list of packages and the configuration to reproduce the issue would be ideal. Even better would be something in an environment like [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). This will let people wanting to help get to investigating the problem without having to research your setup and go through getting started documentation for whatever packages are necessary. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Full answer from @RenaldoMateus's comment:

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the ESLint not correctly identifying the `generated/graphql` as an internal import. By default, ESLint treats all imports that do not fall into the "builtin" or "external" categories as "internal". However, it seems that in your case, it's not recognizing `generated/graphql` as an internal import.

To solve this, you can add a new path group for your `generated` directory in the `pathGroups` array in your `.eslintrc` file. This will explicitly tell ESLint to treat anything from the `generated` directory as an internal import.

Here's how you can do it:

```json
"pathGroups": [
  {
    "pattern": "react",
    "group": "external",
    "position": "before"
  },
  {
    "pattern": "generated/**",
    "group": "internal",
    "position": "after"
  }
],
```

In the above configuration, the `pattern` property is a glob pattern that matches any import that starts with `generated/`. The `group` property tells ESLint to treat these imports as internal imports. The `position` property tells ESLint to place these imports after the external imports.

After making this change, ESLint should stop complaining about the order of your imports.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you should use

```
"import/order": [
  "error",
  {
    "alphabetize": {
      "caseInsensitive": true,
      "order": "asc"
    },
    "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index"],
    "newlines-between": "always-and-inside-groups",
    "pathGroups": [
      {
        "pattern": "react",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "before"
      },
      {
        "group": "internal",
        "pattern": "generated/*"
      }
    ],
    "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["builtin"]
  }
],
```

and if you have more internal you need to specify them

the [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript) will only validate the imports are correct, but it won't mark internal projects as internal